# OutOfMemory Exception while fetching large sized data using QueryOver<> in Linq to Nhibernate

Tags: .net, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I have a asp.net web application that is using Linq to NHibernate in NHibernate 3.0.

In a function, I need to get around 20000 records from a table which contains 10 million records with 20 columns.

I am using Session.QueryOver<>() method for fetching records.

The functional code is:

```
public IList<BatchDetails> GetBatchRecordsOnBatchId_BatchSize(int batchId,int stratingRowdId,int batchSize)
    {
        // If the stratingRowdId will be 0 than frist count of the Batch Records equivlent to the batchSize will be return

        //If the batchSize will be 0 than all the Batch Records starting from the RowId equivlent to the stratingRowdId will be return

        // If both the stratingRowdId & batchSize are 0 than all the BatchReocrds for the BatchId will be return



        if (batchId <= 0)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    //Get Batch data from the Database for the BatchId
                    var batchData = from batchRecords in session.QueryOver<BatchDetails>()
                                        .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId)
                                        .List().Skip(stratingRowdId).Take(batchSize)
                                    select batchRecords
                        ;

                    transaction.Commit();
                    return batchData.ToList();
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();


                    throw;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    session.Flush();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This code is working till the table have 2 lac records.

But after adding 10 lac records in the table, this method throws an error as:

> NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter| Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter| Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter| Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> [DAL.GetBatchRecordsOnBatchId]:Unheld error was occured in the application,Exception : could not execute query
>   [ SELECT this_.ReferenceId as Referenc1_2_0_, this_.AccountNumber as AccountN2_2_0_, this_.AccountStatus as AccountS3_2_0_, this_.AccountType as AccountT4_2_0_, this_.AccountSubType as AccountS5_2_0_, this_.AccountDescription as AccountD6_2_0_, this_.ActivationDate as Activati7_2_0_, this_.CombinedBilling as Combined8_2_0_, this_.PlanAmount as PlanAmount2_0_, this_.PlanCode as PlanCode2_0_, this_.CustomerName as Custome11_2_0_, this_.CustomerEmail as Custome12_2_0_, this_.CustomerPhone as Custome13_2_0_, this_.CustomerAddress as Custome14_2_0_, this_.CustomerCity as Custome15_2_0_, this_.CustomerState as Custome16_2_0_, this_.CustomerZipCode as Custome17_2_0_, this_.PaymentAmount as Payment18_2_0_, this_.PaymentCurrency as Payment19_2_0_, this_.PaymentDate as Payment20_2_0_, this_.TransactionId as Transac21_2_0_, this_.BatchId as BatchId2_0_ FROM TIOTestDB.dbo.BatchDetails this_ WHERE this_.BatchId = ? ]
>   Positional parameters:  #0>3
>   [SQL: SELECT this_.RefereId as Referenc1_2_0_, this_.AccNumber as AccountN2_2_0_, this_.AcStatus as AccountS3_2_0_, this_.AcType as AccountT4_2_0_, this_.AccSubType as AccountS5_2_0_, this_.AccountDescription as AccountD6_2_0_, this_.ActivationDate as Activati7_2_0_, this_.CombinedBilling as Combined8_2_0_, this_.PlanAmount as PlanAmount2_0_, this_.PlanCode as PlanCode2_0_, this_.CustomerName as Custome11_2_0_, this_.Email as Custome12_2_0_, this_.Phone as Custome13_2_0_, this_.Address as Custome14_2_0_, this_.City as Custome15_2_0_, this_.State as Custome16_2_0_, this_.ZipCode as Custome17_2_0_, this_.PayAmount as Payment18_2_0_, this_.Currency as Payment19_2_0_, this_.PayDate as Payment20_2_0_, this_.TransactionId as Transac21_2_0_, this_.bhId as bhId2_0_ FROM bDetails this_ WHERE this_.bhId = ?]

as i am executing this function in a foreach() iteration, 
Although the query executes 1 or 2 times and retrieve data but after that it throws the Out of memory exception.

As an experienced NHibernate developer , i can understand that i need to restructure the LINQ query to optimize its performance .

Also i have searched over the internet but i could not get much information.

An earliest reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your query:

```
from batchRecords in session.QueryOver<BatchDetails>()
    .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId)
    .List().Skip(stratingRowdId).Take(batchSize)
select batchRecords
```

can be simplified to just:

```
session.QueryOver<BatchDetails>()
    .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId)
    .List().Skip(stratingRowdId).Take(batchSize)
```

and it will behave exactly the same. All your `from` and `select` effectively do is to add `.Select(x => x)` at the end of the query.

Now, your problem is that you're calling `List()` too early. What `List()` does is to retrieve all results of the query into memory. If you use LINQ methods after that (like you do with `Skip()` and `Take()`), they will be executed in memory, which is not what you want.

What you should do instead is to move `List()` to the end of the query:

```
session.QueryOver<BatchDetails>()
    .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId)
    .Skip(stratingRowdId).Take(batchSize)
    .List()
```

This way, both `Skip()` and `Take()` will be translated into SQL, which means you won't retrieve all of the data into memory, only the data you actually need. This should fix your OOM.